# Replicar relacion Laravel en NodeJs

Tags: sql, laravel, nodejs

Tengo mis siguientes modelos
StockAuto

```
import { DataTypes, Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import { dbInstance } from '../config/db.js';

const StockAutos = dbInstance.define('stockautos', {
    sa_tipo: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    sa_codigo: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    sa_marca: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    sa_auto: DataTypes.INTEGER,
}, {
    tableName: 'stoauto',
    timestamps: false,
});

StockAutos.sync();

export default StockAutos;
```

Auto

```
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { dbInstance } from '../config/db.js';

import Marca from './Marca.js';

const Auto = dbInstance.define('auto', {
    au_codigo: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    au_nombre: DataTypes.STRING,
}, {
    tableName: 'auto',
});

// Relaciones
Auto.belongsTo(Marca, {
    foreignKey: 'au_marca',
    targetKey: 'mar_codigo',
    as: 'marca'
});

Auto.sync();

export default Auto;
```

Marca

```
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { dbInstance } from '../config/db.js';

const Marca = dbInstance.define('marca', {
    mar_codigo: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    mar_nombre: DataTypes.STRING,
}, {
    tableName: 'marca',
});

Marca.sync();

export default Marca;
```

La relacion que necesito replicar en NodeJs es la siguiente

```
 public function version()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Auto::class, 'sa_auto', 'au_codigo')->where('au_marca', $this->sa_marca);
    }
```

Es para obtener la version correcta en el stock de los autos, porque cuando crearon la tabla nunca definieron claves id de identidad lo que hizo que exista por ejemplo

au_codigo=2 con mar_codigo=1
au_codigo=2 con mar_codigo=2
au_codigo=2 con mar_codigo=3
au_codigo=2 con mar_codigo=4
au_codigo=2 con mar_codigo=5